# How to stop Mediaplayer from Playing audio files twice when button is clicked twice

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have a button, when clicked plays an audio file . but the problem is that when the button is clicked twice the file plays twice .

```
Play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Playing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            String audioUrl = "https://eplayer.000webhostapp.com/Sleep Away.mp3";
            //set up MediaPlayer
            mp=new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mp.setDataSource(audioUrl);
                mp.prepare();
                mp.start();
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move this line:

```
mp=new MediaPlayer();
```

before the listener, because every time you click the button, a new MediaPlayer object is created.
At the beginning of the try block, add this code:

```
if (mp.isPlaying()) {
    mp.stop();
    mp.reset();
    mp.release();
}
```

so the `MediaPlayer` stops and is ready to restart.

Comment: None of your suggestions worked, anymore help please?

Comment: Doesn't the player stop?

Comment: No, it keeps playing on multiple  times i click the button . if i click the buttons 10 times, the audio plays 10 times all at once.

Answer (score 0):

`if(mp.isPlaying())` is probably what you are looking for, just check to see if the media player is playing before trying to start it again. Though you probably want also want to check and make sure its not null and only create a new one if it is. Currently its being recreated each time the button is pressed.